# TYPO3 Solr Indexing of Extension Records (Dont have Detail Page)

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-8.x

I've an installation with TYPO3 8 LTS and there are custom tca entries which are listed with pagination but the records don't have a detail page so I cant able to configure the extension configuration. My client requirement is these records should be indexed with Solr. For eg. a record x may exists in the third page and if we search x in solr the result should be gone to this extension page with page argument 3. Please help me to find a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that is not possible and wouldn't make sense. A record can be listed in several places and several plugins --> one record, indexed once (canonical). Search result listings with belonging information are not stored in the database, so to find out, on which page a record would appear is hard to find out --> it depends e.g. on the sorting, on the entered search phrase, on the results count per pagination page, etc.

That also makes sense from a users point of view: he / she / it searches for a specific phrase and want to see a result, not another list of results.

You should implement a detail page for the records. As a workaround to get closer to your requirements, you can also add another parameter the the listing (id of record) to just show the relevant record in the listing (filter the list by id) to show the listing, but only with the relevant record(s).

Answer (score 0):

The url is just another field in the solr document. So if you don't fill, just don't output it in the template? You can e.g. check the link field in the result or make a condition based on the type of record and just show no link.